# compute nvl(max(c.EmployeeId),0) in slick using scala play?

Tags: scala, slick, nvl

I am using slick in play framework. I need to know how to write the following line in slick:

`compute nvl(max(s.version),0)`

Comment: It is going to help if you let us know what compute, nvl and max are. Are these aggregate sql functions? What do you expect the result to be?